# How to load css, js with http in laravel localhost?

Tags: php, laravel

We are using laravel file manager for the scipt but laravel file manager didn't work in localhost (xampp) because laravel file manager assets linked with https and localhost don't have an ssl certificate. that's why browser didn't load those resources.
is there any way to render those css, js with http?

how those assets linked on the code file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ secure_asset('vendor/laravel-filemanager/css/cropper.min.css') }}">
```

Anyone please suggest how to load those file without https?

Answer (score 0):

Load your assets using `asset` helper

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('vendor/laravel-filemanager/css/cropper.min.css') }}">
```

In your .env file change your `APP_URL` , replace `https` with `http`.

This way the assets will load using http, in your live server's .env file keep the https